# Opposite rings and their corresponding rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For ring $R$, the opposite ring $R^{op}$ is the abelian group $(R,+)$ with multiplicative operation $\circ$ defined by $x\circ y=yx$. I am trying to prove the following propositions.

1. Show that $R^{op}$ is a ring and that $(R^{op})^{op}\cong R$.
2. Show that $R\cong S$ if and only if $R^{op}\cong S^{op}$.
3. Show that $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ if and only if $R$ is a right ideal of $R^{op}$.

What I have so far is:

1) To prove that $R^{op}$ is a ring, we must show that $(R, +)$ is an abelian group, multiplication is associative, and multiplication is distributive w.r.t. addition. By definition of $R^{op}$, we trivially have that $(R,+)$ is an abelian group. Now, for associativity observe that our operation is $x\circ y = yx$. Take elements $a,b,c \in R$. Then, 
            $
   (a\circ b)\circ c = ba \circ c = cba = (cb)a = a \circ (cb) = a\circ (b\circ c)
   $
            Finally, we can show distribution. 
            $
   a \circ (b+c) = (b+c)a = ba + ca = a\circ b + a\circ c
   $, and $
   (a+b) \circ c = c(a+b) = ca + cb = a\circ c + b\circ c
   $. 
            So $R^{op}$ is a ring.

However, I always struggle with showing isomorphism. I am not sure how to proceed for either (1) or (2) in this regard. Also, for (3) does this seem like a typo? If it said $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ $\iff$ $I$ is a left ideal of $R^{op}$ it is easy, but as stated I am confused.

Comment: In 3, there are apparently two things that could b considered typos and we’re not sure which you are referring to. Are you talking about the switch from right to left, or the fact that second of the three R’s in the original statement should be $I$?

Comment: @rschwieb the fact that the second of three R's should be an I.

Answer (score 2):

1) $(R^{op})^{op}$ actually *equals* $R$: it is the same set with the same operations.

2) Hint: Any isomorphism between $R$ and $S$ is automatically an isomorphism between the opposite rings, and vice versa.

3). It should read “$I$ is a left ideal of $R$ if and only if $I$ is a right ideal of $R^{op}$.”

Comment: Re: 3, I think the issue is the use of $I$ versus $R$ ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber hmm, rather than guess we should ask.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you are correct.